# Firebug disables on Breakpoint, Code gets executed

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I'm having issues with Firebug v1.12.5. It's no general issue with Firebug, only with a specific script, but i've got no clue why it is not working.

Every time when I set a breakpoint in this script and try do debug, it takes 1-2 seconds where nothing happens and then Firebug says: "Debugger is not enabled". Anyway, after that the script gets executed correctly.

BUT: If I press the pause button and perform an action, firebug jumps to the correct function and I can debug the script with the "step into"-Button (F11). As soon as I set a breakpoint and press the "play"-button, firebug again says: "Debugger is not enabled".

I would you some of the code but I have no idea which part (bigger script), Firebug debugger even gets disabled if i set the breakpoint during the declaration of some variables in the "onload"-function of the window.

Any help, hints or ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
When I add the "debugger;" command, firebug stops at this line and I can jump through the following lines. Anyhow, if I set a breakpoint, even if its in the next line (which gets executed successfully and can be debugged with the step into command), firebug gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could create a **new** Firefox profile, reinstallation almost never solves
any problem because of Firefox retaining the configuration information when
you uninstall.

Another idea would be to incrementally deactivate other plugins that may disturb the functionality of firebug.

Comment: creating a new Firebug profile helped, though i still have no idea why it is working now :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had face similar issue earlier.. if script is too big and has lot of variables declared holding huge data.. firebug behaves very weiredly in those cases... try to break the script[comment out code selectevely if possible] to find out code whcih is causing this.

Hope this helps !!